# Why doesn't the message POST

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, yii2

**When sending data, an empty value comes in Yii2, why is that?**
Data post: id, name.

*JS*

```js
let is = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").content,
    ss = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-param']").content;

 fetch("http://site.se/react/save-babysitter", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "csrf-param": ss,
   "X-CSRF-Token": is
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
   'id': e.id,
   'name': this.state.ChangeName
  })
  }).then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) =>  console.log(data));
```

*PHP*

```
public function actionSaveBabysitter() {
 $request = Yii::$app->request;
 $post = $request->post('name');

 echo json_decode($post);
```

}

Code 200, post null

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: and what do you expect from 
`JSON.stringify({
   'id': e.id,
   'name': this.state.ChangeName
  })`? `this.` will represent JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the Yii reads post params from `$_POST` global variable. But web server only parses request of body send as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. If you send data with `Content-Type: application/json` they are not parsed into `$_POST` variable.

To force Yii parsing JSON request you have to add json parser into [`yii\web\Request::$parsers`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$parsers-detail) property.

You can do that for example in your `web.php` config file:

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ],
        // ... other configurations for request component
    ],
    // ... other components 
]
```